# ftpd can't change root directory when connecting as a non-root user

Tags: ftp, permissions, embedded-linux, busybox

I have an embedded system running linux and I have `busybox` installed for running different services. One of the services is `ftpd`, which I start like this from the `etc/init.d/rcS` file:

```
tcpsvd 0.0.0.0 21 ftpd -w -v /mnt/flash&
```

I have two users in the system, root and a regular user. Root user can easily connect to the FTP server, but when I try to login with the regular user's credentials, I get this error:

```
ftpd[678]: can't change root directory to '/mnt/flash': Operation not permitted
```

Now, I thought that it must be a directory permission problem, and I started with changing permissions on the `/mnt/flash` directory first, but after this didn't work, I ended up having all my files in file-system including `/` to be owned by this regular user and have drwxrwxrwt permissions (just to find the cause of the problem). But I still get this error.

I have also tried to start ftpd with different root folders, including `/`.

I also couldn't find any config files for the ftpd in my file-system, maybe I need to create one manually? If so, which one and how to tell ftpd to allow user logins?

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after trying some random things, I discovered that user login works fine if there is no directory changing involved at all:

```
tcpsvd 0.0.0.0 21 ftpd -w -v &
```

I suspect that `chroot` is called otherwise and the user does not have a right to do that.